# Why does Excel keep forgetting my network links that use UNC path string?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

First, let me put out, I've googled and googled, and being a regular [StackOverflow Answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900807/spyk3hh), I've even searched all over here. I've tried almost every solution I've found, including solutions based on older versions, such as 2003. Nothing has fixed the problem.

I have a few Excel 2010 sheets at work that I have to maintain daily logs on. Within these sheets, on the top frozen lines, I maintain and update, as needed, network links, that sometimes change due to database changes within the network. The links are fairly simplistic in nature:

```
\\ourWork.com\fakeDir\sample\example\go here\sometimes there\might be\spaces
```

These links *work fine*, <sup>**IF**</sup> I do the exact steps of either of the following:

### New Links

- Click on box
- <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> to add link
- Click on it

### Previously set links (<sub>most often used method</sub>)

- <kbd>ctrl+click</kbd> on the box (<sup><sub>*so it doesn't try to open link*</sub></sup>)
- Click in formula/text bar
- Press enter
- Click link

## However, it ***does not*** work by just opening the file and clicking on the link.

#### At least not always. For some reason, some links on some worksheets will work fine <sup>***AFTER***</sup> I've followed another link on a *separate* work sheet. The later does not seem to work for links on same worksheet?

As aforementioned:

- Using [microsoft-excel-2010](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2010) on [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7)
- Tried the [hyperlink](/questions/tagged/hyperlink) formula
- Tried deleting and reinserting links
- Tried context menu->edit link
- Tried Mapping

  - however, this is unacceptable as network links often change, thus i'd have to constantly remap
  - another problem with mapping is that multiple (2-3) people touch this file and not all of us use the same mapped addresses
- Tried making an entirely new xlsx file and copying everything over
- I've even tried using VBA to insert the links, but same results

I just want to be able to click the links and open the file without having to always click to edit then click to open (the later process described above, that I use most often).

Any Ideas?

Comment: So after you change the path, save the file and then re-open it - it makes you edit the link again before it will work?

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes sir. That it does. It keeps auto-correcting the link to `../../../../../../` at the start, which removes (*as per my example above*) `\\ourWork.com\fakeDir` from the link entirely and replaces all ` \ ` with `/` and all `[spaces]` with their respective counterpart `%20`

Comment: Is the drive mapped on the machine?

Comment: As mentioned, yes, i've tried that. The problem with using a mapped directory (like `z:`) is that the network links are changed as sometimes where files are stored are changed. Thus I really need to use the root network address of ` \\network.com\ `

Comment: I ask because I think there's a [known](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/328440) "non bug" about mappings and link management. Even though the [recommendation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2808316) is to use UNC.

Comment: Ah, something else I should have mentioned and that guy hits the problem with mapping: `"If you change all the links to S:, then the workstations that don't use drive S: for mapping to that location will not be able to access the file"`

Comment: However, the first link you gave me says a lot ... i'll try to reach out to an MVP to see if they've found a good work around, though that could take a week

Answer (score 0):

It'd take manual intervention or some kind of script, but you could try formatting the link as a URL rather than UNC path. For example:

```
file://ourwork.com/share/folder/subfolder%20with%20spaces/photo.jpg
```

You can get the correct path format from a browser. For instance, if you type Ctrl+O in Chrome, then browse to a path, it'll put the URL in the format it wants in the address bar.

Comment: hm, the URL file path thing is an interesting idea.

Comment: I actually just tried this. Worked great ... till I saved the file. Didn't even have to close and reopen (tho i did test that). As soon as I saved it, the links died and quit working.

Comment: Any chance your workbook was originally saved in an older version of Excel? I found this which seems to come close to your problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925893

Comment: I'll give it a try shortly, i'm now a little behind in work. Thanks for the suggestion. I will comment update when I get a chance to try this.

Comment: @Zac Just fyi, I did go through this and eventually even tried completely rebuilding the file within 2010, but still have the same problem